# How to make data in textbox disappear with click of radio button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this form where there is a dropdown list.  When user select the list, the corresponding data appeared in the text boxes.

Now, I need to make the data disappear if the user clicks on the radio button - Yes in that section; not when user click submit at the end of the form.

My code below doesn't make the data disappear.

Here's my code that I have attempted :

```
protected void OtherVendor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // use User entered infor - use Insert ?
    if (OtherVendor.Text == "Yes")
    {
        txtSupplierEmail.Text = string.Empty;
        txtSupplierName.Text = string.Empty;
        txtSupplierName.Text = string.Empty;
        txtSupplierCttPerson.Text = string.Empty;
        txtSupplierCttNumber.Text = string.Empty;
        txtSupplierEmail.Text = string.Empty;
        txtSupplierName.Text = string.Empty;
        txtSupplierCttPerson.Text = string.Empty;
        txtSupplierCttNumber.Text = string.Empty;           
    }           
}
```

And my html code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div id="divAP"
             class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Supplier Information</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4"
                                     runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label"
                                       for="inputRefNo">Vendor :
                                    <span style="color: red">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="input-group col-md-8">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSupplier"
                                                      OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                                      runat="server"
                                                      CssClass="form-control"
                                                      AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label"
                                       for="radios">Others Vendor
                                    <span style="color: red">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">
                                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="OtherVendor"
                                                             runat="server"
                                                             OnSelectedIndexChanged="OtherVendor_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                                             RepeatColumns="2"
                                                             RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                                                             AutoPostBack="true">
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes"
                                                          value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="No"
                                                          value="No"></asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <%--To insert code for letting user filling up Supplier email - to have auto-pop up and enable overwrite etc. --%>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label"
                                       for="inputRefNo">Vendor Email:
                                    <span style="color: red">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-4 control-label"
                                     for="inputRefNo">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSupplierEmail"
                                                 runat="server"
                                                 Text="Label"
                                                 Width="100%"
                                                 CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: So what is the problem ?? What is your question??

Comment: Whats wrong with your code? are you getting any error or exceptions?

Comment: try this using javascript

Comment: why you don't use javascript? is there any problem of that?

Comment: I can't use javascript because it will prevent working for users using mobile phone....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it is a typo or not, Anyway in your markup you were specified as `AutoPostBck` but actually it should be `AutoPostBack`; which means `Bck` should be `Back`

One more suggestion for you, instead of using `OtherVendor.Text` in your condition you can format the condition as like this:

```
 if (OtherVendor.SelectedValue == "Yes")
 {
    // Clear controls here
 }
 else
 { 
   // Do something else
 }
```

Comment: @tangara: Have you checked the `AutoPostBck` in your code? is that a typo?

Comment: It is not AutoPostBack...even though there's a typo.  I tried to change it to AutoPackBack=false like what some forums suggested but it doesn't help also

Comment: @tangara: you have to give `AutoPackBack="true"` to trigger the event in the back end

Comment: I already tried that.  It didn't work.  My last comment I said I changed to false, it didn't work either.  The whole thing is not working.  I am looking for a solution to do this thing.

Comment: Btw, your suggestion of if (OtherVendor.SelectedValue == "Yes") doesn't make the data disappear either.